# Connecting multiple USB-capable ICs to a single port

Tags: usb, hub

I am working on a circuit where multiple components (ICs) are USB-capable for the purposes of programming (MCU), diagnostics, or firmware updates. Ideally, I would like to avoid having multiple ports on my board, so my question is whether I can use an onboard USB hub, such as the [TUS2046x](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tusb2046b.pdf?ts=1687035664102&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTUSB2046B%253Fqgpn%253Dtusb2046b)  to connect each D+/- line for each component, and if so what if any are the pros/cons of this approach?

Alternatively, is there a better way to achieve the same goal, or should I stick with the multiple ports approach?

Just to add, I do not need to pass the VBUS power to each device, my board accepts multiple power type connections (including the VBUS) and passes them to a power priority switch to select the most appropriate source for power the board and components.

Comment: Thanks to @JYelton for cleaning up the question.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can integrate an USB hub.

Downsides are it's more complex but the upside is you can have one USB connector. The other option is to have multiple USB connectors, connected to a PC or hub directly.